# Yii and ajax updating after submit does not render the update form page

Tags: jquery, yii, yii-routing

I'm using the Yii Mvc framework and use ajax and PHP. 
I cannot make it work when request update after create/save comment.
I need to refresh the page after create/save  to make the update/save work.
What am I missing?  how to make the click event not returning to the last controller/action 
called?  thank you in advance for any help.

The steps are the following

```
                                                            **adresses called**
1. the user request the index page   (normal call)          /post/index
   (the page index is rendered)
2. the user click to create comment   (ajax call)     /post/createComment
   (the comment-form is rendered inside the index page)
3. the user click to save the comment (ajax call)           /post/saveComment  
   (the comment is saved and the comment-form is removed)
4. the user clcik to update the comment (ajax call)         /post/saveComment 
                                                            is called again
                                                            nothing happens

if before point 4 I refresh the page

4. the user click to update the comment (ajax call)         /post/updateComment
   (the comment-form with existing comment is rendered)

5. the user click to save the commnt (ajax call)            /post/saveComment
   (the comment is saved and the comment-form is removed)   --> ok
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating page by ajax doesn't work automatically in Yii. You can use CActiveFrom widget and its ajax validating feature or to manually update some page elements with javascript. If you are using CAtiveForm we need to see view and controller source code to help you.